# What are the "ordinary" rational functions from Weierstrass tangent substitution?

Tags: functions, trigonometric-integrals, rational-functions

I was on a meandering stroll through Stewart Calculus, and in my notes I was startled to realize months later that in the exercises I had copied verbatim that [the substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) results in an **ordinary** rational function. That same language is parroted without linkage on Wikipedia.

... does this term, "ordinary," pertaining to a function have some special meaning I should have already known, maybe synonymous with algebraic?

Comment: "Ordinary rational function" (ratio of polynomial functions) as opposed to "trigonometric rational function" (ratio of trigonometric polynomials) maybe?

Comment: @Taladris so long as others find this ambiguous, I'm satisfied that I didn't miss something, haha!